# Rails totaly overiding show method in controler

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wish to change the show method in a controller build with a scaffold.  The code I want to put in the method is.

```
def show
  @url_segment = params[:url_segment]
  @page        = Page.where( url_segment: @url_segment )
end
```

So rather than show using the id to get the page, it uses a field called url_segment.   So I can do things like http://eventpuddle.com/pages/about (rather than http://eventpuddle.com/pages/1) for SEO reasons.

But if I put this code I get an error "
Couldn't find Page with 'id'=about'" as it is still running the original (inherited I guess) code.  It show the code it is running is:

```
def set_page
  @page = Page.find(params[:id])
end
```

Is there a way of getting the method not to do this and only run the code I put in the show method (i.e. not running the inherited code).

Alternativly I could create n new controler and view but wwould rather use the existing one.

I am using rails 5.1.3.

Comment: You can just do that! Try it out, you are supposed to edit the code generated by Rails, in this case especially.

Comment: I did try it out, that's how I know it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with your routes, if you run `rake routes` you'll need to have a route that matches `get /pages/:url_segment` for that controller to work.

By default it uses `:id` in the route, so in your controller try:

```
def show
  @page = Page.where( url_segment: params[:id] ).first
  # ... you need to render the response still
end
```

Comment: Yes, rake routes shows 'page GET /pages/:id(.:format)'.  looking in routes.rb I have 'resources :pages'.  I tried putting '"get 'pages/:section_url_segment', to: 'pages#index' " in later but it still runs the same 'inherited' code.

Comment: OK, so if I comment out the 'resources :pages' I could get it working but this will break the CRUD processing scaffold created.  I'm actually using rails_admin but it feels better just to create a new controller/view and leave the CRUD stuff intact?